# How can you stop a program from listening as soon as you stop talking?

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

I am making a simple program to listen to my michrophone and using google's api convert it to text.
It's going fine but my problem is that when i am stop talking, the program keeps listening and just after few seconds after i stopped talking it stops.

I know its probably a problem with my noise in the background although I have Blue yeti microphone so it should'nt rally happens but still I tried to adjust the noise and yet it showed the same result.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone(device_index = 1) as source:
    print("Say something!")
    #audio = r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source) - Tried also that
    audio = r.listen(source)
    print('Stopped listening!')
try:
    print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio, language="he-HE"))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

As expected the program keeps listening even when i'm not talking for few seconds which makes it really slow and bad..
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adjusting the `pause_threshold` attribute of the `Recognizer`class.
By default, it is set to `0.8`
Found the info by looking at the `Recognizer` source code here: [https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/350397d2fb5db318c877f29ee3dc6e6cbf4a393d/speech_recognition/**init**.py#L508](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/350397d2fb5db318c877f29ee3dc6e6cbf4a393d/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L508)

Answer (score 1):

if all code is correct try with headphone Attached to the PC and please on the headphone setting with microphone on..... so basically program is working but some times microphone is the problem... That's why program is not showing any error .. because it try to listen but not able to understand because microphone or source is the problem....